# Thread 1: signal SIGABRT on button clicked

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5

I am implementing a logout button in my project.
I attached it by using the touch up inside event. When logout clicked, the user is redirected to login view controller but for some strange reason the application dies after a few seconds with the following error. Thread 1: signal SIGABRT.

Logout clicked: (all this method does is erasing the username and redirecting to "Login" view controller)

```
-(IBAction)logout {

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:nil forKey:@"User"];

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];

UIViewController * vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Login"];
[self presentViewController:vc animated:NO completion:nil];

}
```

Login page has nothing when it loads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your signature for logout is all wrong.  You should change the message line to:

```
-(IBAction) logout:(id) sender {
```

You can ignore sender if you like.  Your touch up inside is expecting to send a message to a method which has a parameter, and yours doesn't.  That's why you're crashing.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your code with this:

```
-(IBAction)logout {

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:nil forKey:@"User"];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{
        UIViewController * vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Login"];
        [self presentViewController:vc animated:NO completion:nil];
    }];

}
```

Probably you are showing the new viewController before the old one has been dismissed, even if you do that not animated.

Comment: The problem was as Owen mentioned. I had to add the :(id)sender. As the touch up inside expects to send a parameter to a method. My method did not have a parameter, therefore it failed.